# Open New Tab/Window

Tags: javascript, html

```
$output .= '<a class="icon icon2 shopping-cart ttip add_to_cart_button product_type_'
.$product->product_type.'" data-product_id="'
.$product->id.'" href="'.$link
.'" rel="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="'
.$label.'" onclick="window.open(this.href); return false;" ></a>
```

I tried adding `onclick="window.open(this.href); return false;`, seems right, but once clicked, it opens to new tab and the url changes, but the page is still like home page.

Comment: I don't understand your question well.. may you give more clarification please?

Comment: Do you want a redirection on current page without opening new tab/window or your new tab/window page url is not what as you want?

Comment: Please do your research before posting here. You have already asked this question only to have it closed.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22059596/open-new-window-in-php

Comment: the code which I added is not working well. It opens to new tab but the page it displays is the home not the product, but the url was changed to the id of the chosen product

Answer (score 0):

Opening a link in a new tab is rather simple. If you have even bothered to do some research you'd know that.

I suggest you start reading sites like w3schools...

Even looking at the attributes for an anchor would work... **[W3C Documentation](http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/HTML/Elements/a)**

Comment: @aksu For the most part they are fairly reliable.

Comment: I tried the very simplest html tag target=_new, but it doesn't work

Comment: @user3358936 Did you try _blank?

Comment: yes, I tried _blank and _new but nothing happens so I add onclick="window.open(this.href); return false;" . It works but when it opens to new tab the page it loads is the home page

Comment: I wonder if it depends on the browser. Try different browsers and see how they react. If they any different you may have to check for the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Give the window a name and the attributes width/height.

```
onclick="window.open(this.href, 'myWindow', 'height=200,width=500'); return false;"
```